# Covariance matrix of a non-central Wishart distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose $\boldsymbol{X}\equiv (X_{1},\ldots ,X_{N})^{\prime }$ is a
multivariate $N$-dimensional normal variable
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{X}\sim \mathit{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu },\boldsymbol{\Sigma })
\end{equation}
where$\ \boldsymbol{\mu }$ is the $N\times 1$ expectation vector and $%
\boldsymbol{\Sigma }$ is the $N\times N$ covariance matrix, and define the
following $N\times N$-matrix variable 
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{W}\equiv \boldsymbol{XX}^{\prime }\text{.}
\end{equation}
It is known that $\boldsymbol{W}$ follows a *non-central Wishart
distribution* with $\nu =1$ degree of fredom, which we denote as $\mathit{%
Wishart}(1,\boldsymbol{\mu },\boldsymbol{\Sigma })$.

Now my question is: what is the analytical formulation of the $N\times N$
covariance matrix $\mathbb{C}v\left\{ \boldsymbol{W}\right\} $ of $%
\boldsymbol{W}$?

Namely, in the special case $\boldsymbol{\mu }=\boldsymbol{0}_{N\times 1}$,
then $\boldsymbol{W}$ follows a *central Wishart distribution* with $%
\nu =1$ degree of fredom, or $\mathit{Wishart}(1,\boldsymbol{0}_{N\times 1},%
\boldsymbol{\Sigma })$, and its covariance matrix reads
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{C}v\left\{ \boldsymbol{W}\right\} =(\mathbb{I}_{N^{2}}+\mathbb{K}%
_{N,N})(\boldsymbol{\Sigma }\otimes \boldsymbol{\Sigma })\text{,}
\label{cov}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{I}_{N^{2}}$ denotes the $N^{2}\times N^{2}$ identity matrix
and $\mathbb{K}_{N,N}$ is the $N^{2}\times N^{2}$ commutation matrix.

So I am wondering to find a formulation which generalizes the above covariance matrix for $%
\boldsymbol{\mu }\neq \boldsymbol{0}_{N\times 1}$. Anyone can help and
supply a related reference in the literature?